Why is Jordan Belfort worried about Steve Madden unloading shares?
Jordan Belfort was on a yacht with Donnie and received a phone call from
Rugrat at the Stratton Oakmont office, informing him that Steve Madden was
selling a large number of his shares in the company:

JORDAN: Even though I owned 85% of Steve-c_cks_cking-motherf_cking-Madden Shoes,
the shares were in his f_cking name. This motherf_cker knew I was in trouble
with the feds and was trying to take advantage.

Earlier in the movie, Stratton Oakmont made $22 million in three hours by making
Steve Madden company stock available to the general public:

Donnie: $22 million in three fu_king hours!

It’s confusing why Jordan Belfort is still concerned about Steve Madden
selling his shares, given that Stratton Oakmont previously made a
significant profit from the company.
Why is Jordan Belfort worried about Steve Madden unloading shares?

Madden wasn't selling his shares, he was selling shares that belonged to Belfort but were registered in Madden's name as a way of hiding what Belfort was doing.
So Madden was selling something that, technically, did not belong to him and was pocketing the money. Belfort can't do anything as he's not supposed to own the shares and is already under investigation.

Oddly phrased. If the shares were in his name, wouldn't that mean they do belong to him, legally?
